# what is the exact behavoiur for the "Save e-mail attachments" under the "Incoming E-Mail Settings" inside my announcent list

Tags: list, development, email, configuration, smtp

I am working on SharePoint Server 2013, and i have the following :-

- I configured my environment to allow sending emails to our SharePoint lists.
- I added a new Announcement list , and i set the following under the "Incoming E-Mail Settings" :-

[image]

- now if i send an email which have an image and an attachment, as follow:-

[image]

- then a new list item will be created , as follow:-

[image]

My question is why **only** the image itself was added as an attachment inside the list item (`**image001.jpg**`),, while the word document (which is attached to the original email) was not added as an attachment inside the list item ??... now if i want to view the word document from the list item, i need to access it through the email attachment link (.eml) inside the list item..

so can anyone adivce on this please , is there a way to attach the word document to the list item (same way the image was added as an attachment to the list item ?) ?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting find. You'd think it would do the opposite since the image is in the body of the email.

Comment: @jpollar , so is there a way to force any email attachment to be added as an attachment inside the list item, using event handler maybe ?